# Recursion with Sum

Tags: summation, recursion

Using `RSolve` I tried without success to convert the recursive relation to a non-recursive function. How can I do this?

```
a[0] = c1;
a[n_] := -c2/n Sum[ (n - k) c3^(n - k) a[k], {k, 0, n - 1}];
```

for n$\ge$0 and being c1,c2,c3 some positive constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know if one can get `RSolve` to do this, my guess is no, but I evaluated

```
a[2]//Factor
(* 1/2 c1 (-2+c2) c2 c3^2 *)

a[3]//Factor
(* -(1/6) c1 c2 (6-6 c2+c2^2) c3^3 *)

a[4]//Factor
(* 1/24 c1 c2 (-24+36 c2-12 c2^2+c2^3) c3^4 *)
```

The structure is quite transparent, except for some polynomial in `c2` in each case. The coefficients for those polynomials are in [A066667](https://oeis.org/A066667) and it was then easy to see that an explicit formula is

```
aexplicit[n_]:=-1/n*c1*c2*c3^n*LaguerreL[n-1,1,c2]
(* only valid when n>0 *)
```

For example

```
a[10]-aexplicit[10]//Expand
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extension of the previous answer of @user293787

Instead of

```
aexplicit[n_]:=-1/n*c1*c2*c3^n*LaguerreL[n-1,1,c2]
```

one could also use:

```
aexplicit2[n_] := -1/n*c1*c2*c3^n*Sum[(Gamma[n + 1] (-c2)^k)/(Gamma[k + 2] k! (n - k - 1)!), {k, 0, n}]
```

or

```
aexplicit3[n_] := -c1 c2 c3^n Hypergeometric1F1[1 - n, 2, c2]
```

However, none of these expressions correctly treats the case `n=0`. The only way I could think of is to use `Piecewise` for cases `n>0` and `n==0`.